# IAM- Switch role for AWS access and policies limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My company uses multiple AWS accounts and access to each account is provided via switch roles. We login to a central AWS account using federated SSO and then use switch role to get into the specific AWS account. So, the switch role invariably needs to have a number of policies to grant necessary access. AWS limits that only a maximum of 10 policies can be attached to a role. Is there a way to workaround this? I don't think we can move away from the approach of using switch roles because it is a company-wise decision.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not add the content from the policies into a single policies policy statement?

Comment: Yes, but there is a limit on the size of a policy as well.

Comment: @museshad Can you please elaborate? There isn't a limit on the size of policy AFAIK.